# Which data type should be chosen for a primary key, Long or Integer using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

Currently, I'm working with a web application using Spring 3.2.0, Hibernate 4.2.0.CR1 and Oracle 10g.

Primary keys in Oracle tables are sequence generated and they all have been mapped with a `Long` type in Hibernate entities. In practice, it is hardly possible to have a system without pagination.

I generally use the following method to retrieve a sublist from a list of rows in a database table.

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
              .createQuery("from Entity order by entityId desc")
              .setFirstResult(currentPage)
              .setMaxResults(pageSize)
              .list();
```

The `setFirstResult()` and the `setMaxResults()` methods only accept a type of `int` as their parameter. Of course, the `int` type is more than sufficient for the `setMaxResults()` method but what if someone has numerous rows in a table and he/she needs to retrieve a sublist of let's say 50 rows **starting from beyond**, `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

Assuming there are more than `2,147,483,647` rows in a given table. of course, I can understand that the given value `2,147,483,647` is a big number but a question arises as to why one should use a `Long` type for a primary key, if the `setFirstResult()` method only accepts a type of `int`? I don't see any overloaded versions of this method even with the criteria API that can accept other than `int`, again a system without pagination is rarely seen in reality.